# Existence of $f_{xy}$ if $f_{yx}$ is continuous

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Is there a function $f\colon D\subset\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\ 
(x,y)\mapsto f(x,y)$, such that $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y}$ exists everywhere and is continuous, but $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x}$ fails to exist at any point?

Comment: I'm thinking of $f$ being defined as a Weierstrass function in $x$, for instance $$f(x,y) = \sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac{1}{2^n} \sin(2^n x).$$
Since $f$ is constant in $y$, we have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)=0$ for all $(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2$, and hence $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}(x,y) = 0$ for all $(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2$. However, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)$ does not exist for any $(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2$.